# User made Exception Class

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have to make my own Exception Class for .NET project. Could somebody please help how can I use it in the code? I just to show to MessageBox to user that the images were not found. But I don't know where to do it. Hoping for a good answer.

```
class RijException : Exception
{
    public RijException()
        : base() { }

    public RijException(string message)
        : base(message) { }

    public RijException(string format, params object[] args)
        : base(string.Format(format, args)) { }

    public RijException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException) { }

    public RijException(string format, Exception innerException, params object[] args)
        : base(string.Format(format, args), innerException) { }
}
```

Now I want to use it:

```
   try
   {
       afbeeldingPictureBox.BackgroundImage =   
        Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Borden\Stilstaan en parkeren\Parkeren toegelaten.png");  
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException)
   {
            throw new RijException("Can't find the images");
   }
```

**Edit**

```
try
        {
            try
            {
                afbeeldingPictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Borden\Stilstaan en parkeren\Parkeren toegelaten.png");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                throw new RijException("ImageNotFound");
                //MessageBox.Show("Afbeeldingen konden niet worden geladen");
            }
        }
        catch (RijException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not able to load the image...");
        }
```

Comment: I don't know where to code the messageBox.

Comment: Change `throw new ...` to `MessageBox.Show()`?

Comment: whereever you finally catch the exception. also check if you need your exception class to be `public`

Answer (score 3):

Your example could be improved, but before that let's take a more useful example.

Imagine that you have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var processor = new FileProcessor();
            processor.Run();
        }
        catch (RijException exception)
        {
            //what will I get here.
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses the following classes:

```
public class FileProcessor
{
    private string _myFileName;

    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            var fileLoader = new FileLoader();
            Process(fileLoader.Load(_myFileName));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            throw new RijException("Can't find requested file");
        }

    }

    private void Process(object file)
    {
        //some logic

    }
}

public class FileLoader
{
    public object Load(string myFileName)
    {
        //throws FileNotFoundException
    }
}
```

So the call stack will be like this:

[image]

If we modify the code in the main method to print the stack trace, what do you think that we get?

```
try
{
    var processor = new FileProcessor();
    processor.Run();
}
catch (RijException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.StackTrace);
}
```

The correct answer is:

[image]

See? The stack trace shows that the error happened in `FileProcessor` while it really happened in `FileLoader`. The reason to that is this code:

```
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
   throw new RijException("Can't find requested file");
}
```

When you catch an exception and throw another one you must always include the original exception as the inner exception. Otherwise it will be hard to understand where the exception originally occurred.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
   throw new RijException("Can't find requested file", ex); //includes inner
}
```

Another problem is the exception message: `"Can't find requested file"`. Ask yourself. If you get that message in a log file, would you be able to figure out what went wrong? At least give some context information.

Finally you have another problem. Best practices for designing exceptions says that they should be able to get serialized. To do that you need to include the serialization constructor and mark the exception as serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class RijException : Exception
{
    public RijException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public RijException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
    {
    }

    //serialization constructor
    protected RijException(
        SerializationInfo info,
        StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
    }
```

Finally I would therefore write your exercise like this:

```
try
{
    var filename = @"..\..\Borden\Stilstaan en parkeren\Parkeren toegelaten.png";
    try
    {
        afbeeldingPictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(filename);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        throw new RijException("Failed to load " + filename, exception);
    }
}
catch (RijException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not able to load the image...");

    //now you would have all information required
    //to figure out where and why something went wrong.
}
```

**Summary**

1. Always include inner exceptions
2. Provide useful context information so that you can figure out what went wrong
3. Make sure that exceptions can be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not a great idea to catch an exception that you cannot do much about.  Just catching the `FileNotFoundException` and then throwing a new `RijException` that essentially conveys the same information is not usually done.

> I just to show to MessageBox to user that the images were not found. But I don't know where to do it.

The most direct way to restructure your code to show the message box is

```
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can't find the images.");
    //Don't do this: throw new RijException("Can't find the images");
}
```

You really do not want your custom `RijException` to take on the responsibility of displaying the `MessageBox`.

Comment: Use an Exception class... to do what exactly?  What is the specific requirement in conjunction with your custom exception?

Comment: I have to write my own Exception Class named RijException here. Would you please take a look at the code after **edit**. Is it good or not?

Comment: @Gurpreet.S: While it is bad style to catch and rethrow with a custom exception, I assume this is some sort of learning exercise.  With that assumption, your updated code demonstrates the principal of a custom exception, and should work fine.

Comment: why is it a bad style? I would rather say that it depends on the use case

Comment: @jgauffin: I cannot think of a single use case where it makes sense to catch an exception that I can do nothing about, just to rethrow a different exception that conveys essentially the same information.  If there *is* something you can do about it (in the context if your application and requirements), then it does make sense.

Comment: @Gurpreet.S: I would suggest you give this article by Eric Lippert a read.  It is a short and excellent overview of how to handle exceptions in your programs http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: `different exception that conveys essentially the same information`, for that I agree. I thought you mean in general terms.